# Photoswipe working on browser but not on devices

Tags: css, cordova

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to use photoswiper in a PhoneGap app. I'm trying to use this example :

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PFqVs/][1]
```

that works great in any browser, but just don't work on any device.

When I open, it's like I have a css issue since I don't see any king of style and when I touch any image, I just see it full size but can't swipe to see the next one.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

May be you should mention all sites with external resources in the [WhiteList](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html)?